# C# Multiple Constructors with parameter variations design pattern

Tags: c#, design-patterns, constructor

I'm trying to refactor some code that is passing different combinations of parameters depending on the type of configuration an object needs.  For example:

```
public MyWidget(string server, string port)
{
...
}

public MyWidget(string server)
{
...
}

public MyWidget(bool createAThing, 
                string nameOfThingToBeCreated, 
                string server, 
                string port)
{
...
}

public MyWidget(bool createAThing, string nameOfThingToBeCreated)
{
...
}
```

...etc

I don't want to use properties, because it feels like it's hiding some possible dependencies e.g. the object might require the server to be passed in if there's the port property has been assigned.  Don't get hung up on the example params, this is just something I'm pulling out of the air.

I looked at the Builder pattern, but it's not quite what I need.   Any suggestions would be great!

I'm using .NET 2.0

Comment: What's not working for you? This question is very general

Comment: You can use [constructor chaining](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/271582/Constructor-Chaining-in-Csharp) for some of your refactoring.

Comment: probably not very useful, but in .NET 3.0 you have object initialisers, which means you dont need to have tons of constructors. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx

Comment: @James - It's not that it's not working, I just don't want to create every possible combination of constructors that I might need.  I'm trying to figure out if there's a way to do it more elegantly.

Comment: @JaneDoe this is a great suggestion, but the developer would still need to know what combination of props are needed for each scenario.  I'm trying to figure out a way to corner the developer into passing in everything they need for each scenario.  I feel like I've seen a solution to this somewhere.

Comment: With .NET 4.0, the [Optional Arguments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx) feature can really help. Don't know if this is possible for your case.

Comment: It is possible that the class has too many responsibilities, in particular when looking at the different constructor signatures - perhaps a redesign to more classes with less responsibilities each would be the right way forward.

Comment: Its also possible that this may need to work like DbConnection. There's simply a natural tension of the use cases and the resulting hidden dependencies. This is why there's a lot of places where you can get Invalid Operation exceptions with DbConnection. There they also use a builder pattern with DbConnectionStringBuilder.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a configuration object and pass that to your constructor.
Something like this:

```
public class WidgetOptions
{
    public string Server { get; set; }
    public string Port { get; set; }
    ... 
}

public class MyWidget
{
    public MyWidget(WidgetOptions options)
    {
         Server = options.Server;
         Port = options.Port;
         ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I gave some though to this, but it still requires the developer to know exactly what combinations are necessary for a given situation.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, if the intent is to always create a "valid" object such that the object is not ever in a half-configured state, then the Builder pattern is appropriate.  The builder holds the data points until they are all assigned and can then create a completely configured object in one go.

But it sounds like you don't trust your developers to read the documentation to know what to configure...*you do provide documentation, right ;)*

In that case, perhaps provide a set of builders that each only exposes the properties that relate to the "mode" your final object needs.

So something like this (pseudo code and made up, since you didn't provide any hinst about what you are really trying to model)

```
WidgetBuilder
+ whatever properties are common to all widget creation
+ MakeWidget

VectorWidgetBuilder : WidgetBuilder
+ get/set Lines
+ MakeWidget 

BitmapWidgetBuilder : WidgetBuilder
+ get/set Image
+ MakeWidget 

AnimatedWidgetBuilder : WidgetBuilder
+ get/set Images
+ get/set FrameRate
+ MakeWidget
```

A variation of this would be to define these permutations as various `WidgetOptions`, as Master Morality called them, but each distint set of options is its own class.  So you might have `VectorWidgetOptions`, `BitmapWidgetOptions`, and `AnimatedWidgetOptions` that just exposes the related set of properties.